# "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" when trying to set node attributes in networkX

Tags: networkx

below is the code that is giving the TypeError...

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
datamuse = pd.read_csv(NetworkDatasheet.csv',index_col=0)
print(datamuse)
G = nx.DiGraph(datamuse.values)
nx.draw_random(G, with_labels=True)

dc= nx.degree_centrality(G)
bc=nx.betweenness_centrality(G,normalized = True)
ec=nx.eigenvector_centrality(G)

nx.set_node_attributes(G,'degree centrality',dc)
nx.set_node_attributes(G,'betweenness centrality',bc)
nx.set_node_attributes(G,'eigenvector centrality',ec)

G.nodes()[1]['degree centrality']
```

the values in the dictionary (e.g: dc) are float like 0.029411764705882353

Comment: In the third line of your code, did you miss a left quote in the filename?

Comment: Can you please give us that file also ?

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code should be replaced by:

```
G.nodes(data=True)[1][1]['degree centrality']
```

You need to have the associated properties of your nodes, hence `data=True` otherwise you only get the node ids.
Then when you do `G.nodes(data=True)[1]` you actually get a tuple `(nodeId, data_dict)` so to access the data values, you need to get the second element, hence `[1]`.

Comment: @AbheekSambyal if an answer works please accept it. It's how you show the community that your issue is solved. (Same for the other answer I gave you earlier ;)). Thanks